# Symfony: switch language without loosing input in form

Tags: forms, symfony, translation

I have a form that can be switched into different languages. The problem is that when the language is swtiched, all the input is lost since the page is refreshed without saving.
I would like to either keep the input of the variables after switching language or avoid that the user changes the language while filling the form.

The button used to switch languages changes the locale and shows the content in the corresponding language:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
{% if (app.request.getLocale()) == 'de' %}
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">{{ 'navbar.language'|trans }} <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li class="active"><a href="#"> De</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'fr'})) }}"> Fr</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'it'})) }}"> It</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'en'})) }}"> En</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
{% endif %}
{% if (app.request.getLocale()) == 'fr' %}
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">{{ 'navbar.language'|trans }} <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li class=""><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'de'})) }}"> De</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#"> Fr</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'it'})) }}"> It</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'en'})) }}"> En</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
{% endif %}
{% if (app.request.getLocale()) == 'it' %}
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">{{ 'navbar.language'|trans }} <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li class=""><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'de'})) }}"> De</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'fr'})) }}"> Fr</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#"> It</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'en'})) }}"> En</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
{% endif %}
{% if (app.request.getLocale()) == 'en' %}
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">{{ 'navbar.language'|trans }} <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li class=""><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'de'})) }}"> De</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'fr'})) }}"> Fr</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'it'})) }}"> It</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href=""> En</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
{% endif %}
</ul>
 </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
```

I am thinking of two possibilities for now. Either a JavaScript function that shows and hide the elements or to have an intermediary page to first choose the language and then be forwarded to the selected version of the form.

How could I achieve one of these possibilites:
1. keep input after switching language
2. JavaScript function
3. Intermediary page for language selection

Comment: Temporary save user inputs, change language then restore them, or use something like https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms to prevent user to switch language if they already started filling the form.

Comment: Thank you! Could you elaborate on your first option? and I am not quite sure how to use dirtyforms. Do you have an example similar to my case?